# How to modify BeanInfo of a classe (generated by jaxb xjc)?

Tags: java, annotations, jaxb, javabeans, beaninfo

I created some classes using JAXB XJC. They follow this pattern (some properties with getters and setters and xml annotations):

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "School", propOrder = {
    "info",
    "students"
})
public class School {

    @XmlElement(name = "Info", required = true)
    protected Info info;

    @XmlElement(name = "Students", required = true)
    protected List<Student> students;

    public Info getInfo(){ return info;}

    public void setInfo(Info value){ info = value};

    public List<Students> getStudents(){ 
       if (students == null) {
            students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        }
       return students;
    }

    public void setStudents(List<Student> elements){
       if (students == null) {
            students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        }
       students.addAll(elements);
    }
```

When I use `java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo` and `BeanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors` to get the class BeanInfo I can see that my `School` class has a property called `students` with the `WriteMethod` being `setStudents(List)`. I believe that the BeanInfo of this class was generated following the default rules of Bean, according to  [Java Beans specification](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf?AuthParam=1588860159_ad8c7fb78bb6e0b01bc1f339fd9027e0):

> If we discover a matching pair of `get<PropertyName>` and `set<PropertyName>` methods that take and return the same type, then we regard these methods as defining a read-write property whose name will be `<propertyName>`.

So, how can I change the BeanInfo of this class? More precisely, I want to set the `WriteMethod` of the property `students` to be another method that does not follow the default rule mentioned above (it would be `public void setStudent (Student student){...}`). How can I do this?

Only to make sure it is clear... When I use `java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo` and `BeanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors` to get the class BeanInfo **I want to see** that my `School` class has the **property** `students` with the `WriteMethod` being **my new set method** (`setStudents(Student)` that does not follow the default rule).

I saw some things [here](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/256), but it wasn't enough for me...

Thank you!